# SQL table does not backup with bcp C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-backups, bcp

I am using the following codes to backup tables in a SQL database.

```
 //Passenger table backup
 psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
 psi.FileName = "bcp.exe";
 psi.Arguments = @"Passenger out Backup\backupPassenger.csv -T -d CrashFlight101 -w";
 Process.Start(psi);              

 //Pilot table backup
 psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
 psi.FileName = "bcp.exe";
 psi.Arguments = @"Pilot out Backup\backupPilot.csv -T -d CrashFlight101 -w";
 Process.Start(psi);

 //User table backup
 psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
 psi.FileName = "bcp.exe";
 psi.Arguments = @"User out Backup\backupUser.csv -T -d CrashFlight101 -w";
 Process.Start(psi);
```

For some reason it doesn't want to backup the User table and I can't seem to see why. Each table has the same permissions and were created the same way. It is a simple database design with no schema structure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Any messages in the Event viewer?

Comment: well... what *does* happen? does it report an error? or does nothing whatsoever happen? or...

Comment: `User` is a keyword in T-SQL - have you tried using `[User]` instead?

Comment: I'm also implicitly assuming that those command lines work ok when executed directly... (except now I made it explicit; ahem)

Comment: I used try and catch blocks, but no errors were thrown. It creates .csv files for all the tables except the user tahble

Comment: marc_s, it worked. Can't believe I forgot that.